# How to use devcon install a driver on win 10?

Tags: devcon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgfxK.png)

When i using devcon.exe install a driver (iclude notestmode.inf, notestmode.cat, notestmode.sys)
I get error for cmd : devcon failed. It still gives an error even if I run with adminitrator permissions.

How to fix ?

i want install driver on win10 using devcon. Pls help me